# Under what conditions would $S^{-1}F$ be a free left $S^{-1}R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

So I am thinking of a ring $R$ with multiplicative identity $1_{R}\ne 0_{R}$, $F$ is a free left $R$-module, and every element of $S$ is not a zero divisor, and $0_{R}\in S$. Under these conditions wouldn't it be trivial to conclude that $S^{-1}F$ is a free left $S^{-1}R$-module.

How would one prove such a statement?

Comment: Is $R$ commutative? If not, then the localisation construction needs some qualification. In any case, if $0 \in S$, the localisation is bound to be trivial: the only ring in which $0$ is invertible is the trivial ring $\{0\}$.

Comment: $R$ is a commutative ring.

Comment: Did you really mean to specify $0_R \in S$? If you did then $S^{-1}R$ is the trivial ring and your statement about free modules is true for trivial reasons.